# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in localhost\websites\mvc-pattern\app\start\Starter.php on line 7
```

The error line is commented with `//this is the error line`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        class Starter{
            protected $controller= 'Home';
            protected $method= 'index';
            protected $param= array();
            public function __construct(){
                $url=this->url();//this is the error line
                // prepare controller
                if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')){
                    this->$controller= $url[0];
                    unset($url[0]);
                }

                require_once '../app/controllers/'. $controller. '.php';
                this->$controller= new this->$controller;

                //prepare method
                if(isset($url[1])){
                    if(method_exists($controller,$url[1])){
                        this->$method= $url[1];
                        unset($url[1]);
                    }
                }

                this->$param= $url ? array_values($url) : array();
                call_user_func_array([this->$controller,this->$method],this->$param);
                 }
            public function url(){
                $url= $_GET['url'];
                $url= explode('/',rtrim($url,'/'));
                return $url;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is an undefined constant... constants can't be used as objects.

```
            $url=this->url();//this is the error line
```

It should be `$this->url();` - note the `$`. You have the same error in multiple other places as well.